# How to extract JITed code from Hotspot VM?

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

As proof of concept for my project I am trying to extract JIT compiled code and keep it in a file which I would like to be able to execute separately. The code I have currently extracted (from nmethod) has all the relocation addresses fixed. I want to extract code from the point where references to addresses in instructions are possibly in form of offsets? I understand there are references in instructions to other memory locations which are outside current CodeSection/CodeBuffer. Dealing with them is not my concern for now. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: So you basically want to see how a certain method has been JIT compiled and "run" that later? "run" here is the very complicated term - I just wonder _how_ you would be able to do that. otherwise an interesting question IMHO

Comment: I understand the complexity entailing this so I am taking on this bit by bit and my first problem is dealing with relocation. As far as I have seen there is no reference table created in native code which I can use when I load the method in memory later..